# Creating new column dataframes function and lapply: providing too many variables

Tags: r, function, dataframe, lapply

I am currently trying to write a simple custom function which creates a new column in an existing data.frame, based on a multiplication of two existing columns.

Following that I would like to apply the function across multiple data.frames in the global environment with lapply.

I however already fail to write the custom function, as I am getting the follow error (based on my example data posted below): "In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = list(A = 1:20, B = c(1L,  : provided 3 variables to replace 2 variables"

I am aware that this is an absolute basic question, but I have not found a fitting answer to this specific question online and simply cant wrap my head around it myself.

Thanks in advance for any help!

I have already tried using "return(x[i])" at the end of the function, as it has been recommended in other posts, or also leaving out the [i] (which I am only using as I saw it another question), which did not change anything.

Using this function gives the error stated above

```r
set.seed(40)
A <- seq(1:20)
B <- rbinom(A, 1, 0.5)
df1 <- data.frame(A, B)

set.seed(40)
C <- as.numeric(seq(1:50))
D <- as.numeric(rbinom(C, 1, 0.5))
df2 <- data.frame(C, D)

FUN = function(x, i){
  x[i]$Mul = x[i]$A*x[i]$B
}

FUN(df1)
```

This function correctly gives the new values but of course does not create a new column in the existing data.frame

```r
FUN = function(x, i){
   x[i]$A*x[i]$B
}

FUN(df1)
```

I would then like to apply the function with to all other data.frames including "df" in the name

```r
lapply(mget(ls(pattern="df")), FUN)
```

I excpet to have a new column in df, df$Mul, with the values c( 1  2  3  0  0  0  0  8  0  0  0 12  0  0 15 16  0 18  0 20). Such a column, I cant manage to create.

Comment: why do you need `lapply` for this? Isn't this `df$Mul <- df$A * df$B` ?

Comment: @RonakShah: Because I would like to apply the function to multiple data.frames, all containing a certain naming pattern. Your option would only work for a specific data.frame, or am I mistaking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get all the dataframes together in a list using `mget`

```
list_df <- mget(ls(pattern="df"))
```

Change the function using `transform`

```
FUN = function(x){
   transform(x, mult = x[, 1]  * x[, 2])
}
```

and apply it to list of dataframes

```
list_df <- lapply(list_df, FUN)
```

You'll have all the dataframes with new column. Although, it is better to keep such dataframes in list instead of having objects of multiple dataframes in the global environment. However, if you want the dataframes separately again you can do

```
list2env(list_df,envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The dfs however have different numbers of rows, applying the function with lapply therefore gives the following error "Error in data.frame(list(C = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 50, 20" . I will add this to the main question!

Comment: @SebSchn Different number of rows won't matter but if they different column names then you might need to identify them with column number instead of names. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much Ronak! The updated version works perfectly! Different row names should not be present in this case, but I certainly see the use of your solution for future endavours. I marked your solution as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tidyverse` methods

```
library(tidyverse)
mget(ls(pattern = "^df\\d+$")) %>%
     map(~ .x %>%
            mutate(mult = (!! rlang::sym(names(.x)[1])) *
                          (!! rlang::sym(names(.x)[2]))))
```

---

Or using `reduce`

```
mget(ls(pattern = "^df\\d+$")) %>% 
    map(~ .x %>% 
             mutate(mult = reduce(., `*`)))
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late answer! While your solution also does calculate the multiplication value, it does not create a new variable/column in the specific dfs containing the new values on my side.

Comment: @Seb You may need `list2env` for doing that, but I wouldn't recommend that way.  Instead, it would be better to keep it in a `list`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I also went back and noticed that your code works just fine, also creating the new variable/column - I simply did not specify it to create a new list. Adding ```r: list_df <- ``` to your solutions (of course) does the job!

Comment: @Seb Yes, I didn't specify the assignment as I thought it is too basic.

Comment: Yes of course, I actually do not know why I even wrote that first comment, I will attribute that to a lack of sleep! Unfortunately I can't upvote your solution as I do not have the reputation yet and I already accepted the answer of Ronak.

Comment: @Seb It's okay and thanks for clarifying the issues.  I hope this will also give some  alternate way of thinking